# Backup Work dir to git before shutdown

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, backup, git

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I have a directory named Work which I want to backup to github everytime I poweroff my computer.
I have written the backup script and it's working fine but I cannot run it before shutting down. Please help.
Here are the contents of backup_work.sh

```
cd /home/kaustab/Work
git add .
git commit -m "Daily Backup"
mkdir /home/kaustab/test 
git push origin master
echo "Backed up"
read -n 1 -s -r -p "Press any key to continue"
```

Comment: GitHub documentation for connecting via ssh (rather than https): https://help.github.com/en/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for all your help but I have managed to solve this. 
What I did was edit the ***shutdown.desktop*** in /usr/share/applications and changed the exec to my script. This is what my modified ***shutdown.desktop*** file looks like.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shutdown
Comment=Backup and power off the computer
GenericName=Shut Down
Exec=gnome-terminal -e /home/kaustab/.scripts/backup_work.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility
Icon=/usr/share/unity/icons/shutdown_highlight.png
NotShowIn=GNOME-Flashback;
X-AppStream-Ignore=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=session-shortcuts
```

At the end of the ***backup_work.sh*** script I have added the line `gnome-session-quit --power-off` to give me the options of the power menu. 
Thanks to [QIS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/362831/qis) for pointing out to use ssh instead of https to connect to github. I will be trying that later.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a script at shutdown by following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416299/execute-command-before-shutdown-reboot).

Basically, you can place the script in `/etc/rc6.d/`, and make it executable. The one drawback with this approach is that any script in the above directory will run as the root user, which can change file permissions and cause issues later. The alternative is to leave your script in your home directory, and add the following script in `/etc/rc6.d`

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo -u kaustab /home/kaustab/backup_work.sh
exit 0
```

Finally, you should remove the call to `read` as well (or add a timeout), since it will ask you for a keypress before shutting down and block the shut down.

**Systemd approach**

The rc6.d script approach above is the legacy sysv-init approach to running scripts at shutdown. With newer versions of Debian/Ubuntu, it's safer to use a systemd unit file to run the script at shutdown.

Place the following script in `/etc/systemd/system/backup-work.service` ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/795406)) and run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup work directory
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
# This works because it is installed in the target and will be
#   executed before the target state is entered
# Also consider kexec.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=kaustab
Group=kaustab
ExecStart=/home/kaustab/backup_work.sh  # your path and filename

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target
```

Comment: I tried the systemd approach but it is not working. My script has execute permissions. Also when the script will run I will be asked for my username and password.

Comment: What I want is to first run my script and if the script runs successfully only then the system will shutdown. Is ther any way to do this?

Comment: If you are using HTTPS to connect to Github, then yes, it will ask for a password. You are better off using passwordless SSH to connect to Github. A systemd spawned service will not have a terminal access, so you will not see a request for username/password.

Comment: For blocking the shutdown, you can consider using a service like [reboot-guard](https://github.com/ryran/reboot-guard)

Comment: Isn't there a need to enable the script after `daemon-reload`?